# relative directory with bibtex

Tags: bibtex, input

I am currently trying to have a reference for each of the `\input` of my document. The working tree looks something like this:

```
project
 |--main.tex
 |--chapter1
       |--chapter1-1.tex
       |--chapter1-1.bib
```

I have a compile script resting at `project` level, and `main.tex` is:

```
\begin{document}
  \input{chapter1/chapter1-1.tex}
\end{document}
```

Inside `chapter1-1.tex`, I tried:

```
\bibliography{chapter1-1}
```

which will not work. If I do:

```
\bibliography{chapter1/chapter1-1}
```

it will work. Is there a way to call relative directory for the bib file inside `chapter1`?

Comment: You can imagine `\input` just taking the indicated `.tex` file and pasting it into your `main.tex`. That explains why everything is happening at the folder level of `main.tex` and you need to give the path as `chapter1/chapter1-1` to your `.bib` file. You'd need a way to tell `chapter1-1.tex` that it is being called from a different directory. Maybe https://ctan.org/pkg/import can help you.